# htaccess - redirect whole website to another with exact extentions but rediret directory/pages to different directory under different domain

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache

I need to redirect whole website from one domain to another with the exact extention, BUT only all pages in specific directory should be redirected to another directory on new website. `http://www.website.com/dir/page-123` (all pages starting with `"page-*"` to `http://www.newwebsite/dir/`. Tried many options, nothing works.

Tried:

```
RewriteRule ^dir/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ oldwebsite.com/dir
RewriteRule (.*) newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^dir/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ oldwebsite.com/dir
> RewriteRule (.*) newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Not sure what you thought these directives were doing, or why you were using two directives and rewritting to the `oldwebsite` in the first one?

If you need to redirect to a different host, then you must specify an absolute URL, including the *scheme*, in the *substitution*. eg. `http://newwebsite.com/`.

> But the last rule takes control on first one

Yes, it would, since you don't include the `L` (`LAST`) flag on the first `RewriteRule` and the second rule matches *everything*. `RewriteRule` directives chain together (the output of the first directive is used as the input for the second, etc.), so you need to stop that from happening.

However, you presumably need these to be external `R`edirects, not *internal rewrites*.

Try the following in the `.htaccess` file in the specific subdirectory of `oldwebsite.com` that you want to redirect from (eg. `example.com/dir/.htaccess`).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(page-.*) http://newwebsite.com/newdir/ [R=301,L]
```

This redirects all pages that *start* with "page-" in the subdirectory (eg. `dir`) to `http://newwebsite.com/newdir/`.

Comment: Thank you @w3dk - new dir with htaccess worked as magic!